# Is LINQ implementation of Entity Framework inappropriate?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, sum

## Tested objects' classes as preamble

```cs
namespace EFConsoleApp.Models.Db
{
    [Table("a")]
    public class TableA
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Column("amount")]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        [Column("a_id")]
        public int AId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EFConsoleApp.DataAccesses.Db
{
    public class ContextA : DbContext
    {
        public string DefaultSchema { get; private set; }

        public ContextA() : base(GetConnecting(), true)
        {
            DefaultSchema = "public";
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            => modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(DefaultSchema);

        public static NpgsqlConnection GetConnecting()
        {
            return new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["postgreSql"].ToString());
        }

        public virtual DbSet<TableA> A { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Question

### Why I get the following exception when executing the code below with no data in table?

※ I'm using Entity Framework 6.2.0 and Npgsql 4.0.7 and .NET Framework 4.6 .

Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.
> Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Executed code:

```cs
// _ctx's type is DataAccesses.Db.ContextA .
// ContextA table has no data.

var sum = _ctx.A
    .Where(e => e.AId == aid)
    .Select(e => e.Amount)
    // .ToString() shows "SELECT \"Extent1\".\"amount\" FROM \"public\".\"a\" AS \"Extent1\" WHERE \"Extent1\".\"a_id\" = @p__linq__0"
    .Sum();
```

### And why I don't get the same exception when executing the code below with no data in list?

```cs
var list = new List<TableA>();
var qList = list.AsQueryable(); // To imitate return type of .Select()

// qList has no data.

var sum = qList
    .Where(e => e.AId == 1)
    .Select(e => e.Amount)
    .Sum(); // sum = 0
```

Called LINQ methods are the same (as I think...), but result is different.

### There are also other attempts

#### Attempt #1

```cs
var sum = <Resource>
    .Where(e => e.AId == a
    .Sum(e => e.Amount);
```

In case of EF, the same exception.
In case of in-memory object (`new List<TableA>().AsQueryable()`), sum is 0.

#### Attempt #2

```cs
var sum = (from a in <Resource> where a.AId == aid select a.Amount).Sum();
```

In case of EF, the same exception.
In case of in-memory object (`new List<TableA>().AsQueryable()`), sum is 0.

#### Attempt #3 (Tested only with EF)

```cs
var sum = _ctx.Database
    .SqlQuery<int>("SELECT amount FROM a WHERE a_id = @par_a_id;",
        new NpgsqlParameter("par_a_id", aid))
    .Sum();
```

Surprisingly it works and sum is 0.

---

So, what's wrong with EF's implementation of LINQ?
Or problem with me because I can't understand something how it works under hood?

---

## Update against @MindSwipe 's answer

I tried to execute sql with `SUM` directly in database and EF.
※ Still with no data in table.

```sql
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM a WHERE a_id = 1;
```

Query above returns `null`.

```cs
var sum = _ctx.Database
    .SqlQuery<int>("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM a WHERE a_id = @par_a_id;",
        new NpgsqlParameter("par_a_id", aid))
    .Single();
```

Code above cause the same exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException:
> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null.
> Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

So, at least I understood why exception occurs.

## As conclusion

In case to avoid exceptions when working with `SUM`,
obviously, the code below is the most safe?

```cs
var sum = _ctx.Database
    .Where(e => e.AId == aid)
    .Select(e => e.Amount)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Sum();
```

## Update against @Aron 's comment

Using [IDbCommandInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbcommandinterceptor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) I got raw sql.

```cs
var sum = _ctx.A
    .Where(e => e.AId == aid)
    .Select(e => e.Amount) // #1
    .Sum(); // #2
```

```sql
-- #1
SELECT                                                "Extent1"."amount"                   FROM "public"."a" AS "Extent1" WHERE "Extent1"."a_id" = @p__linq__0"
-- #2
SELECT "GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1" FROM (SELECT CAST (sum("Extent1"."amount") AS int4) AS "A1" FROM "public"."a" AS "Extent1" WHERE "Extent1"."a_id" = @p__linq__0) AS "GroupBy1"
```

Comment: @Selvin, I have no any data records in table, and amount is ‘NOT NULL’.

Comment: ok what is `aid` ?

Comment: @Selvin, not nullable int.

Comment: Well, maybe because on postgres sum of no element is null ... it's in the postgres documentation (simple google result for  "postgress sum returns null") *It should be noted that except for count, these functions return a null value when no rows are selected. In particular, sum of no rows returns null, not zero as one might expect. The coalesce function may be used to substitute zero for null when necessary.* from docs of Aggregate Functions

Comment: For any query that might return a null, add a cast; `.Select(e => (int?)e.Amount)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Major re-write of the answer, the old one was incorrect.

---

In PostgresSQL `SUM` returns `null` when there are no elements to sum up. To test this, here's a short script:

```sql
drop table if exists temp;
create table temp (id integer, amount integer);
insert into temp (id, amount) values (1, 0);
select SUM(amount) from temp where id = 2;
```

Check the output and it will be `null`, not `0` or any other number

You can copy and paste the script into [this](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html) site if you don't want to use a local database.

To protect against this case you need to either

1. Cast select nullable amount, and sum it, returning 0 if none were found, like so:

```cs
var sum = _ctx.A
    .Where(x => x.AId == aid)
    .Select(x => (int?) x.Amount)
    .Sum() ?? 0;
```

2. Make `Amount` nullable by making it be `public int? Amount {get; set;}`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will check it. But anyway, if postgresql returns null, why EF doesn’t translate it to 0, while in-memory objects return 0? Why behavior is different? As I think, I’m behind of EF, and I should not  care about what postgresql return to EF. Is it bad implementation in EF or everything ok?

Comment: The difference is how it's executed. Entity Framework translates the LINQ query (the expression chains) into SQL and then transforms the values returned back. While the in memory doesn't do it. So it comes down to implementation details, C#s `Count` method will return the default if it's ran on an empty collection, while Postgres returns null, it's up to you to decide which is "correct".

Comment: To elaborate on what EF does: It translate the entire expression into SQL, so the entire query on your database is something like `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM A where A.AId = 0` for example, and this query returns `null`, which EF then tries to convert to an `int`. P.S I'm about to update the query in the answer with another one that should do it one query not 2

Comment: I couldn’t check does EF’s ‘sum’ translate the entire expression into SQL or it does ‘sum’ to result of previous result of query. So... if I could check that, maybe I wouldn’t ask this question... anyway thank you for answer!

Comment: @Yeheshuah SQL, the language, specifies that SUM over NULL will produce the same result as all other aggregate functions, ie NULL. This is neither an EF nor a PostgreSQL issue. [Why does ANSI SQL define SUM(no rows) as NULL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25435/why-does-ansi-sql-define-sumno-rows-as-null)

Comment: @MindSwipe checked your query and updated question.

Comment: @Yeheshuah Futher, EF does NOT do any translation; it provides a framework for translations to take place. The actual translations are done in the EF provider, in this case  [EfCore.Pg](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg). You can use [EF interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) to view the generated SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, as a translation layer. Something always gets lost in translation. I can put in a PR for a fix for this particular issue if you would like...

Comment: @Aron, thanks for useful comments! I got sql from executed LINQ in question: `SELECT "GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1" FROM (SELECT CAST (sum("Extent1"."amount") AS int4) AS "A1" FROM "public"."a" AS "Extent1" WHERE "Extent1"."a_id" = @p__linq__0) AS "GroupBy1"`

Comment: @Aron, Would PR clear up the behavior of `Sum()` and fix it, if it's really incorrect?